# Can't ping router with Realtek [10ec:8168] (rev 06) Ethernet adapter

Tags: networking, ethernet, router, 15.10

I have a TP-LINK TL-WR841N connected to my main desktop through an Ethernet cable. I've recently installed Ubuntu on dual-boot, but while it works on the other OS, it doesn't on Ubuntu. I've tested on a Ubuntu desktop through the same cable, and it works. I've just reinstalled Ubuntu to version 15.10, but nothing. What can I do? Any help is appreciated

EDIT: `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'` output:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'` terminal command.

Comment: Done, added it at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install another driver. Connect to internet an alternative way and run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

If you can't connect an alternative way, you will have to download this package and dkms separately.

Run

```
sudo modprobe -r r8169
sudo modprobe r8168
```

or reboot after the installation.

Comment: Just did that, didn't work. `lspci` still has the same output

Comment: If you did it correctly. the output should be different. The kernel module will be `r8168`.

Comment: Tried to reinstall if,  it's saying r8168-dkms is the newest version, but `lspci` didn't change

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: God, I'm stupid. But it worked! Thank you